# default gateway not set when using bond0 interface

Tags: networking, routing, ifconfig, bonding, ifupdown

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    address 10.66.7.11/24
    gateway 10.66.7.1
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-slaves eth2 eth3
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 200
    bond-updelay 400
    bond-lacp-rate 1
    up ifconfig bond0 10.66.7.11/24 up
```

when I bring the bond0 interface up, it works, but the default gateway is not set

```
# route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.66.7.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
```

I have to set the default gateway manually, and then everything works fine:

```
route add default gw 10.66.7.1 bond0

#route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0         10.66.7.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
10.66.7.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
```

why is my default gateway not set automatically, when I have it defined in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among multiple *ifupdown* implementations, I'll consider it's [`ifupdown`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/ifupdown) (implementation "v1") and the [`interfaces(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5) configuration as seen on Debian.

The *bond0* stanza **should not** use the keyword `manual`:

> [The manual Method](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5#The_manual_Method)
>
> This method may be used to define interfaces for which no
> configuration is done by default. Such interfaces can be configured
> manually by means of `up` and `down` commands or `/etc/network/if-*.d`
> scripts.

which will configure *bond0*'s bond properties (on Debian probably through the `ifenslave` package which adds plugin scripts in `/etc/network/if-*.d`) but not IP properties.

So nothing is done: both `address` and `gateway` options are ignored but manual commands brought through `up` scripts are executed, such as:

> ```
> up ifconfig bond0 10.66.7.11/24 up
> ```

which *manually* runs a command which happens to be adding an address on *bond0*: that's why *bond0* has an address, the LAN route automatically added by the kernel from this address, and no gateway.

The keyword `static` (which will still do what the `manual` method would do but will also configure IPv4 with `inet static`) should have been used:

> [The static Method](https://manpages.debian.org/ifupdown/interfaces.5#The_static_Method)
>
> This method may be used to define Ethernet interfaces with statically
> allocated IPv4 addresses.

to have *ifupdown* configure IP addresses and the default gateway on it.

---

So simply replace `manual` with `static` and remove the non-needed `up` entry. The configuration should then be:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 10.66.7.11/24
    gateway 10.66.7.1
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-slaves eth2 eth3
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 200
    bond-updelay 400
    bond-lacp-rate 1
```